# Change size of actionButton and its label

Tags: html, css, r, shiny

How can I make an `actionButton` and its label smaller, but still centered in the button icon?  I have been able to accomplish making both the button and the text smaller, but the result is a small button with small text that isn't centered in the button.  I think I'm probably approaching this incorrectly.  Here is an example where the button/text gets smaller but the result is a button with the text not centered.

```
library(shiny)

shinyApp(
    shinyUI(fluidPage(
        inputPanel(
            ## Original
            actionButton('button', 'Hi'),

            ## Text is smaller
            gsub('Hi', '<font size="1">Hi</font>',
                 actionButton('button1', 'Hi')),

            ## Text is smaller and button is smaller, but text is outside of button
            gsub('Hi', '<font size="1" align="center">Hi</font>',
                 actionButton('button2', 'Hi', style='height:20px'))
            )
    )),
    shinyServer(function(input,output){})
)
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You should really just focus on the HTML and CSS here. There's nothing that's really R and shiny specific here. An `actionButton` is just an HTML `<button>`. You can set properties for font-size and padding (the space around the text).

Here's one way to reduce the padding and decrease the font-size

```
actionButton('button2', 'Hi', style='padding:4px; font-size:80%'))
```